# «Третьего и последующего ребенка/детей»

Tags: согласование

Согласование «...за рождение третьего и последующего ребенка/детей». Склоняюсь к использованию «ребенка».

Answer (score 1):

Поискал в интернете. Повсюду пишут "при рождении третьего и последующих детей".

**Добавление от Grizzly**.
Ну, кроме [этих страниц](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=ZvjJX_-ABOPyqwGG4KnYDQ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoFCCEQoAFQwVBYkWhg8HBoAHACeACAAfwBiAGoDJIBBjAuMTAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj_y42U-bPtAhVj-SoKHQZwCtsQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), про которые гугло-счётчик говорит, что их почти в два раза больше, чем [этих](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=dfjJX57jGoiprgSznZmIAQ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAgQHjoECAAQRzoGCAAQBxAeOggIABAHEAUQHjoICAAQCBAHEB5QzpwNWMupDWD6rg1oAHAEeACAAa4CiAHECZIBBzAuNy4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwje8beb-bPtAhWIlIsKHbNOBhEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5).

Comment: Не представляю, как можно что-то искать в интернете, если не уметь пользоваться поисковиками. Добавил примеры запросов прямо в ответ — в комментарий они не помещаются.

Comment: @grizzly  так как правильно по итогу?

Comment: Думаю, оба варианта допустимы, хотя я бы предпочёл сказать "за рождение третьего и каждого последующего ребёнка".